# The animation of switching between Activities does not work if the Activity has the "taskAffinity =""" parameter or before Picture in Picture

Tags: android

After I had the need to move the Activity to a separate process using " taskAffinity="" ", the transition animations that I specified in the style stopped working. I tried using overridePendingTransition and ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation but that didn't help. Also, the animations I set in code with overridePendingTransition don't work after I switch to Picture In Picture mode and then back again. As far as I understand, the point is that the animations do not work when switching between different processes, but it seems to me that there must be some way to do this. I will be very grateful if someone knows how to implement the animation when moving between aActivity , when they have different process.

Manifest my Activity:

```
<activity
      android:name=".modules.media.video.player.VideoPlayerActivity"
      android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout"
      android:exported="false"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:resizeableActivity="true"
      android:taskAffinity =""
      android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
      android:theme="@style/VideoPlayerTheme"
      tools:targetApi="n">
```